# terminal command npm problem with thirdweb

Tags: hardhat, thirdweb

so in this video he is running npm run deploy in its web3 folder and trying to use /connect to thirdweb features i really dont know hat is it after running npm run deploy i am selecting hardhat and then it is showing waiting status  and afterwards the thirdweb webiste is getting opened i dont knopw hat to do their i am stuck i tried connecting my metamask wallet but still no result , do i have to wait for the result

so in this video he is running npm run deploy in its web3 folder and trying to use /connect to thirdweb features i really dont know what is it after running npm run deploy i am selecting hardhat and then it is showing waiting status